# How to add custom content inside ACF tab

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add some dynamic custom content inside ACF tab but can't find any filters or actions or hooks to do this please any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's dynamic content, you could use `acf/prepare_field` ACF Filter.

> This filter allows you to modify a field right before it is rendered onto the page. By this time, the field has been validated and it’s value loaded.

As in my previous response I'd place an empty `Message` field in the Tab. Then, use the filter (e.g in `functions.php`) like this:

```
function my_acf_prepare_field( $field ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) :
        $dynamic = 'dynamic';
        ?>
        <p style="padding: 1em;">
            This is <?= $dynamic ?> content
        </p>
        <?php
    endif;
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/prepare_field/key=YOUR_MESSAGE_FIELD_KEY', 'my_acf_prepare_field');
```

Check [the docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfprepare_field/#usage) for options on filtering only a field (by key or name) or all message fields (so, by type).

It works:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks @Jordi, it works but if you had more than one tab like I do it seems the custom content show in all the tabs so, I added some css and js to solve this Thanks.

Comment: Mmm... if you only place the empty message field in one tab and you hook your filter with the correct `acf/prepare_field/key=KEY` option, it shoudn't appear on the other tabs...

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across this. The above was helpful, but a more efficient way of accomplishing this objective is:

```
function prepare_acf_message_content( $field ) { 

    if ( is_admin() ) {
        
        $field['message'] = 'Got your content right here' ; 

    }

    return $field ;

}

add_filter('acf/prepare_field/key=FIELD_KEY_HERE', 'prepare_acf_message_content') ;
```

Other message field elements you can consider adjusting will be visible if you dump `$field` - for example:

```
{
"ID":151718,
"key":"field_5f4d95a6d04ee",
"label":"Widget Output",
"name":"acf[field_5f4d95a6d04ee]",
"prefix":"acf",
"type":"message",
"value":false,
"menu_order":27,
"instructions":"",
"required":0,
"id":"acf-field_5f4d95a6d04ee",
"class":"","conditional_logic":0,
"parent":78177,
"wrapper":{"width":"","class":"","id":""},
"message":"",
"new_lines":"",
"esc_html":0,
"_name":"widget_output"
,"_valid":1,
"_prepare":true
}
```